# C# Optimizing for loop with a small body

Tags: c#, optimization

I have a C# implementation of a neural network that includes a for loop that does a large number of small computations. Unfortunately, the loop's performance is quite poor. What could I do to optimize the code?

Comment: Your question is way too broad. We need to see some actual code before we can begin to help. Did you do any profiling of the code yourself to find where the bottlenecks are?

Comment: Just throwing multi-threading and SIMD and whatever isn't magic either, if you want something to be truly fast you will have to do less work - ie use a smaller network.

Comment: @Evan_K2014 I recognize maybe you do not want to share your "secret sauce" so to speak, but it just is difficult to tell you how to optimize something without seeing the code that is the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your bottleneck is loop overhead, then the way to handle that is to do more in a single loop.  For example:

pre-optimization loop:

```
var ints = new int[1000];

for (var x = 0; x < 1000; ++x)
{
    //do work on one element
}
```

post-optimization loop:

```
for (var x = 0; x < 1000; x += 10)
{
   //do work on x + 0
   //do work on x + 1
   //do work on x + 2
   //do work on x + 3
   //do work on x + 4
   //do work on x + 5
   //do work on x + 6
   //do work on x + 7
   //do work on x + 8
   //do work on x + 9
}
```

The same can be done with streams by processing larger chunks at once.

If you are working with arrays and are fortunate enough for them to be blittable, then you can use pointers to bypass array bounds checks on access as well as - usually - eliminate the translation of indexes into memory addresses by making your loop variable a pointer rather than an index.

The Optimization chapter of any of the Code Complete series of books will teach you all this and many more.